# C# How to obtain a variable’s actual larger positive and negative number

Tags: c#, variables, numbers, max, min

I have **C#** code with the next situation

2 variables: `double qty1` and `double qty2` that are frequently receiving 2 different positive/negative numbers.

Then there is a variable `double currentResult` **that receives the sum of qty1 and qty2 (positive/negative numbers) and currentResult changes its value every time qty1 or qty2 receives new quantities**. The values of currentResult are not being stored anywhere, it is not needed because currentResult is just for display purposes only, so it is just displayed in a the screen being showed as actual information and done. Until this moment we are talking about displaying a simple sum result, so please don't focus your answer in this part because is not the important one.

Ok, **what I need is** to get 2 variable values from currentResult:

- The largest positive number (`double maxResult`) among all the numbers that currentResult has ever had, being up to date at the present time.
- The smallest negative number (`double minResult`) among all the numbers that currentResult has ever had, being up to date at the present time.

Let's give a random quick **example**: when the program starts, let's imagine the first result currentResult displays is 7, then -1, then 3, then -8, then 10, then -4, -11, 15... And it keeps updating its current value when it receives new data, then:

```
- I need **maxResult** first displays as its value the number 7, then the number 10 as new max number among all currentResult has had until now, then 15, and so on.

- I need **minResult** first displays as its value the number -1, then the number -8 as new min number among all currentResult has had until now, then -11 and so on.
```

For now, I don't the need to store previous maxResult/minResult values, only their current (last) Max/Min values to remain visible in screen until arrives any new Max/Min number.

Here I use the word "display" to visually understand what I need as final result but **the main I need is the necessary code to obtain maxResult and minResult** because I haven't found a way to get this 2 values from a variable.

Please note here we are not talking about a pre-defined list of numbers in which we need to find the Max and the Min numbers, no, here we need to base the results from the values of single variable (currentResult), working with the numerical values it has as time progresses.

Comment: When you say "based in 1 single variable that keeps frequently changing its value" - by what means is that variable changing? Because whatever changes that variable just needs to check the min/max stored and update as necessary. It will help you get an answer if you show code, a [mcve] is optimal.

Comment: So you want to show running minimal and maximal values from a list? You really found a strange way of describing it.

Comment: "in real time" makes no real sense here. I guess you mean something like "immediately". DotNet has no "real time" properties or guarantees.

Comment: Thank you

About "based in 1 single variable that keeps frequently changing its value" I mean that "double currentResult" is a variable that receives a Total Sum value from others variables (positives/negatives numbers) and as those others variables keeps changing the calculations values, then currentResult will be changing its current value too, I didn't include code cuz this is about simple sum values, anyhing sophisticate

About "real time" it just mean that maxResult/minResult do and show the current max/min value inmediately as currentResult has a new value that meet with the criteria

Answer (score 1):

Without more information it is hard to answer your question well, but in general what you're looking for is [`Math.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.min?view=net-5.0) and [`Math.Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.max?view=net-5.0) both of which take 2 values and return the min or max respectively.

Therefore, your code where the value is updated would look something like the following:

```
historicMin = Math.Min(currentResult, historicMin);
historicMax = Math.Max(currentResult, historicMax);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is my first post here and I didn't know the answers could be so fast. I didn't include more information because it's just about simple total sum of values, really nothing sophisticate. When you start the program you can see currentResult shows values like 2.50, 5.00, -1.25, 0.00, -3.75, -10.00, 3.00, 17.50... So It updates its current value when it receive a new total sum calculation. what I need is to obtain the max >0 value and the min <0 value to display these 2 updated values that only change when currentResult get a newer value that meet with the criteria